# why the tables not deleted when we uninstall the module?

Tags: magento2

why developer does not use UninstallInterface for every modules they develop so module can uninstall completely. is there any problem to delete tables from database after uninstall modules?

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/Uninstall.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{
    /**
     * Module uninstall code
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function uninstall(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        $connection->dropTable($connection->getTableName('your_table_name_here'));
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there should not be an issue with manually deleting the tables. Obviously make absolutely sure you don't need the data.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's because the module should be installed via composer to be able run uninstall script.